# How can i resolve the this problem in java 8

Tags: java-8

> can anyone suggest the code snip in java 8

**Constraint :** Even number multiple by 5

Details :
Input:[1,2,3,4,5]

Output : [1,10,3,20,5]

Code Snip :

```
Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);     
List<Integer> resStream = intStream
      .filter(i->(i%2==0))
      .map(i->(i*5))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
resStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: This is trivial.  What have you tried?  Please post your attempt at solving this.

Comment: @WJS I have added the code snip - Expected the output like : [1,10,3,20,5]

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
//define list of integer input = [1,2,3,4,5]
//define list of integer output = []

//for each item in list:
//  if item mod 2 = 0
//     output.add( item * 2 )
//  else
//     output.add( item )

//print output
```

Your attempt was a good start. I fixed it:

1. remove the filter, because you want to retain all items for the mapping
2. add a simple conditional `if..else` into the map-step lambda - equivalent to [WJS suggested ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264401/5730279)
3. chain all the streaming steps together

```java
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  // no filter but conditional map
  .map(i-> {
    if (i%2==0) 
      return (i*5);
    else
      return i;
  })
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Try it online on [IDEone](https://ideone.com/V2Xemz).

Comment: I need code snip in java 8 in single stream operations like filter and map

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Your given transformation "constraint" is a mapping-rule, a conditional mapping (where the `else` was omitted as change-nothing): if "Even number multiple by 5", else just the leave the number.

Answer (score -1):

By using `filter` and then `map` you only pass on the `even values` and multiply those by `5`.  So the answer would be `[10,20]`.

The map simply uses a conditional `(?:)` expression. `a ? b : c`.  If `a` is true, return expression `b`, else return `c`.

```
Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 
List<Integer> resStream = intStream.map(i->(i%2==0) ? i*5 : i).toList();
System.out.println(resStream);
```

prints

```
[1,10,3,20,5]
```

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Did this solve your problem?